# Independent time in several mobile platforms

Tags: android, ios, objective-c

I need to create clock which should be always synchronized with Android, iOS etc..

Clock should be:
independent. (User or something else could not change time)
synchronized. (time should be the same on Android, iOS etc..)
work offline. (internet connection shouldn't be required)

I would appreciate for any suggestion.

Now i am looking at gps time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

GPS signal will only be available outdoors.

Instead try using the NTP or SNTP protocol.

(By the way, Android's internal clock is synchronized using [NITZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NITZ) and [NTP/SNTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)) 
You can search the Android source code for reference implementation.

Comment: I am reading now abou NTP. But still i would need internet connection ?

Comment: Yes[.](http://unix4lyfe.org/time/)

Answer (score 0):

GPS time is very precise but it is not always available as well as internet.

You should use phone clocks and sync them over internet with server by calculating delta in second or miliseconds.

At 7:00am Internet available
`{ServerDelta}` = `{ServerTime}` - `{PhoneTime}`

At 8:00am GPS Available

`{GPSDelta}` = `{GPSTime}` - `{PhoneTime}`

At 11:00am you can calculate `{GPSDelta}` and `{ServerDelta}` if you have `{PhoneTime}` and deltas
But you will not know if server changed clocks or phone changed clocks by syncing with time server. Every day you phone corrects time and it may loose/gain 5 seconds everyday.

Comment: Using GPS time is not practical indoors. From what I know.. indoor GPS time is the same as the [system time](http://unix4lyfe.org/time/) which tends to drift.

Comment: {PhoneTime} could be different in Android or iOS phone. So time will not be the same. Ii would be great to have second precision. I think this could be fine if user can't change phoneTime

Comment: `{GPSDelta}` and `{ServerDelta}` are used to get `{GPSTime}` and `{ServerTime}` when they are not available from `{PhoneTime}`